# Change password of parse user using parse SDK in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform, passwords, forgot-password

I am developing android application and using parse.com as back end storage. But I got stuck on change password. I am able to send the reset password mail using parse.com sdk to particular email. but I want to change the password using application as well without log `enter code here`in using old password.

Function to send mail:-

```
public void resetPassword() {

    CustomProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", getResources()
                              .getString(R.string.please_wait));

    ParseUser.requestPasswordResetInBackground("test@gmail.com",
        new RequestPasswordResetCallback() {
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                CustomProgressDialog.dismissMe();

                if (e == null) {
                    // An email was successfully sent with reset
                    // instructions.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.reset_password_sent), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong. Look at the ParseException
                    // to see what's up.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.reset_password_fail), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

And also able to launch the application from mail using declaring the permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use for that next method [ParseUser.setPassword()](http://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#setPassword(java.lang.String)).

Idea is next, if user is logged in then you don't need to check old password, because it was already entered and applied by Parse.com. So you will have 2 fields `New Password` and `Confirm New Password`. Users enters them and application changes it on server.

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
parseUser.setPassword(password);
parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (null == e) {
            // report about success
        } else {
            // report about error 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @gio, Is there any way to do this functionality without log in. Because my purpose is to do forgot password feature implementation into app on the log in screen.

Comment: @jagdish, unfortunately, no. User need to be logged in to set password or use provided feature to reset password by Parse.com

Comment: ohhh, last query, I am getting mail from parse.com for reset password and it having the user name and token as well in the url. Can wo do anything based on token to perform any action? Thanks again for quick response.

Comment: @jagdish I'm not sure that you'll be able to access to that email for each user. You won't build your logic on those url, because Parse.com may change its format in any moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for support... @gio +1 for good and reliable response.